# SQLServer Module Saltstack, pillar issue

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, salt-stack

Hi I'm writing a module on sql server for saltstack. I'm having some trouble getting the pillar. if some one can help me to undertand how to pillars works.

I want to know the difference between having the - at the front of the variable there is an example.

```
=== top.sls===

sqlserver:
  db_name:
    user: name of the user
    passw: password
=== end top.sls ==

**=== top.sls===
sqlserver:
  db_name:
    -user: name of the user
    -passw: password
=== end top.sls ==**
```

the full code is at https://github.com/shepax/sqlserver_saltstack

Answer (score 0):

This is actually yaml syntax. Dashes mean that the items are in a list.

See more here: http://salt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/yaml/#rule-three-dashes